# Images randomly fail to set heights correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a particularly annoying front end bug that I can't seem to diagnose correctly let alone fix after several attempts. You should be able to see an example of it at http://fmhgifts.com where the product images at the bottom of the page fail to display their correct height dimensions consistently as seen here:

[image: Incorrectly displayed]

As you can see there doesn't appear to be any consistency in which images are impacted, nor even as to on each load of the page. For reference it should look like this:

[image: Correctly displayed]

It should also be noted that by clicking on any of the options in the "sort items by" drop down menu then causes it to work correctly!

Any help on the matter would be infinitely appreciated as I have already spent many hours on this (though I am far from a CSS expert) and I am hoping someone more experienced will be able to help identify the problem for me.

Comment: sounds like maybe you have javascript doing positioning for you based on image position/size and when some elements are only partially loaded, the javascript runs, with incorrect info.

Comment: you could move jQuery into a `$(window).load(function(){...})` to test that out.

Comment: Please try to produce a minimal test case, or at least post the relevant code snippets here. See also: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997/186560)

Comment: Is there a way that I can establish what bits of JS are involved in the layout in the same way that I can for CSS using the Web Developer Tools or something similar? The JS in production is all minimised which doesn't make it amusing for anyone trying to help with this.

I "believe" this is the script in question but it is already set to wait for the page to load https://github.com/mhoad/there-goes-my-paycheck/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/filter/setting.js

Answer (score 0):

So the solution to this lies in slightly tweaking how the code for this javascript is called. Where the original code was:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#portfolio').isotope({
      // options
      itemSelector : '.item',
      layoutMode : 'fitRows'
    });
    jQuery('.option-set').find('a').click(function(){
              if ( jQuery(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
                      return false;
                    }
                    jQuery(this).parents('.option-set').find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
               jQuery(this).addClass('selected');
    });   
    jQuery('#filters a').click(function(){
      var selector = jQuery(this).attr('data-filter');
      jQuery('#portfolio').isotope({ filter: selector });
      return false;
    });

});
```

Changing the first line from

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){...}
```

to

```
$(window).load(function(){..}
```

resolved the issues it was having. Thanks to everyone for their help in helping me get to the bottom of this as well. It's much appreciated.